# How do I host a Realm server, either on my local machine or AWS/3rd party hosting site?

Tags: ios, swift, database, server, realm

I am building a messaging app with Swift and using Realm DB. I need a server with the Realm DB so that all devices can read/write to it as needed.

How do I set up a Realm server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This guide does not help you: https://realm.io/cn/docs/realm-object-server/?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions to install the Realm Object Server can be found in Realm's documentation, notably the "Deployment" section here https://realm.io/docs/get-started/deployment/

There are detailed step-by-step instructions for macOS, Digital Ocean, RHEL/CentOS 6, RHEL/CentOS 7, Ubuntu 16.04 and AWS/AMI, with more coming.